# TypeScript: Can IntelliJ Generate an Interface from an Object or a Type from a Function?

Tags: typescript, intellij-idea

I have a question that may seem trivial, but I would appreciate your assistance or any information you may have about it.

While using the IntelliJ IDE (Ultimate Edition), I noticed that there is a default setting that displays type hints, as seen in the example below:

[image]

As shown, the type hint for the DEFAULT_PROPS object is displayed. I am wondering if there is a way to create a TypeScript interface from this type hint.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: `type x = typeof DEFAULT_PROPS` ? Or an interface?

Comment: You can copy from popup hint if there is one